# Does a real function in two arguments exist so that it is linear in one argument and injective at the same time?

Tags: functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ with $f(x, y) = a(y) x + b(y)$ and $a(y)$ and $b(y)$ are fully arbitrary functions.

To clarify, $\mathbb{R}_+ = [0, \infty)$ (that is, I include 0 in the positives)

Comment: What tags are proper? And how to actually use LaTeX on this site?

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) syntax.

Comment: `\R` has never been a built-in $\LaTeX$ macro: use `\mathbb{R}`.

Comment: I have been used to Quora where it was used. Thank you all for the editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Suppose there were.  Note that $f(0,y)=b(y)$. This means that $b(y)$ must be injective. Let $y_1\neq y_2$.  this implies that $b(y_1)\neq b(y_2)$.   Suppose $ \exists y_0$ such that $a(y_0)\neq 0$. Then we can find $x_i$ such that $f(x_i,y_0)=b(y_i)$ namely $$x_i=\frac {b(y_i)-b(y_0)}{a(y_0)}$$  As $x_1\neq x_2$ they can't both be $0$ so we are done in this case.  Of course, if $a(y)$ is identically $0$ then the problem is trivial so we are done.

Comment: Thank you, I actually have figured it out myself (an argument similar to this one) and wanted to write it.

Comment: Follow up: is it possible for the function f to be well behaved for constant y? (Bounded on any interval, though the bound doesn't need to be the same for all intervals)

Comment: I will answer my own follow up with a yes: find any general function obeying the properties in the question then apply a function such as 1/(x^2+1) on it to limit its image. Then an affine transform will move that image where I want it.

Answer (score 0):

If $a(y) > 0$, one has $f(\mathbb{R_+}, y) = [b(y), +\infty)$. It means that at most one value of $y$ satisfies $a(y)>0$. For other values of $y$, one has $a(y) = 0$ otherwise $f$ would reach negative values. But if $a(y) = 0$, then $f(x, y)$ does not depend on $x$ hence it is not injective.

The answer is NO.

Comment: a(y) and b(y) are fully under our control.

Comment: @PaulStelian No, they are not because $f$ must be injective and have non negative values.

Comment: Well under the restrictions imposed by injectivity they are chosen by us.

Comment: b(y) and a(y) must be positive anyways because otherwise negatives can be reached.

Comment: What I mean is that a(y)=0 can be excluded

Comment: And what I said above is that $a(y)>0$ must be excluded too except for a single $y$ because of injectivity!

Comment: Well... Oh, so that would be an alternative, harder to understand proof, nevertheless a proof.